# Existe algum plugin que sirva de máscara e validador para horários 24h?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pesquisei mas só encontrei plugins para hora com "select" e com os horários no formado AM/PM.

Gostaria de um que a pessoa pudesse digitar e ficasse nesse formato:

```
23:59:59
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é mais ou menos simples de fazer, ou seja uma máscara para inserir `:` quando se está a inserir numeros.

Pode ser mais complexo para não permitir numeros grandes demais e excluir letras.

Um exemplo simples seria:

```
document.getElementById('hora').addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    var str = this.value.split(':').join('');
    if (str.length > 6) str = str.slice(0, 6);
    var formatado = str.match(/.{1,2}/g).join(':');
    this.value = formatado;
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hupmfr9/

Essas 4 linhas de código explicadas:

- remover `:` eventuais que hajam na string
- tirar o ultimo caractere caso seja longo demais
- partir em pedações de dois caracteres e colar de novo com `:` entre eles
- colocar de novo no input

Answer (score 1):

Veja se isso lhe ajuda:

```
var time = new Date(params.tweetDate),
h = time.getHours(), // 0-24 format
m = time.getMinutes();
```

Font:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/date.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Utilizei o plugin jQuery-Mask-Plugin: http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

E fiz as validações de horário 24h que eu precisava. Ele não permite 24:59:59, 23:69:59 ou 23:59:69,  por exemplo.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jQueryMask/jquery.mask.js">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
            onKeyPress: function (a, b, c) {
                if (a.length == 2) {
                    if (parseInt(a[1]) > 3 && parseInt(a[0]) == 2) {
                        a = a[0];
                        $(c).val(a);
                    }
                }
            },
            translation: {
                A: { pattern: /[0-2]/ },
                C: { pattern: /[0-5]/ },
                B: { pattern: /[0-9]/ }
            }
        };

        $('.time').mask('AB:CB:CB', options);
    })
</script>
```